# Enumeration of corner points of a polytope

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-programming

Given a linear program, is there any library or available code to enumerate all the corner points of a polytope ?.

PS: Simplex method finds one corner point depending on the objective, but I need to enumerate all the corner points.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Software recommendations and code requests are off-topic here.

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/vertexenum/man/enumerate.vertices.html or https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7894-con2vert-constraints-to-vertices something like this? This is of course still off-topic in my opinion.

Comment: As @Evil says, requests for libraries or code are off-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic] and http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/660/755.  I'm placing the question on temporary hold to give you a chance to edit it.  Asking about an algorithm would be on-topic, but in this case, the number of corner points can be (and often is) exponentially large, so any such algorithm would have very bad worst-case running time.  Is that what you want?  If so, please edit the question to ask about that.  Otherwise, if your question can be made suitable here, please edit accordingly.

Comment: This is the [vertex enumeration problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem). Take a look at this question on MO: [Computionally efficient vertex enumeration for (convex) polytopes](http://mathoverflow.net/q/203966/91764).